# How to make exceptions for certain words in regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I'm very new in programming and regex so apologise if this's been asked before (I didn't find one, though).

I want to use Python to summarise word frequencies in a literal text. Let's assume the text is formatted like

```
Chapter 1
blah blah blah

Chapter 2
blah blah blah
....
```

Now I read the text as a string, and I want to use `re.findall` to get every word in this text, so my code is

```
wordlist = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', text)
```

But the problem is that it matches all these `Chapter`s in each chapter title, which I don't want to include in my stats. So I want to ignore what matches `Chapter\s*\d+`. What should I do?

Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: Try `r'\b(?!Chapter\s*\d)\w+\b'`

Comment: The use `re.findall(r'\bChapter\s*\d+\b|\b(\w+)\b',s)`

Comment: Use a simple regex, and then remove the ones you don't want afterwards.

Comment: @BryanOakley perhaps under most circumstances I'll do so, after all I'd prefer to deal with strings rather than fiddle with regexes, except when, for example, there are *lots of* exceptions I want to make in the regex queries (say I want to ignore Chapter X, Section X, Subsection X etc.), and removing them afterwards could be messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solutions

You could remove all `Chapter+space+digits` first :

```
wordlist = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', re.sub(r'Chapter\s*\d+\s*','',text))
```

If you want to use just one search , you can use a negative lookahead to find any word that isn't preceded by "Chapter X" and does not begin with a digit :

```
wordlist = re.findall(r'\b(?!Chapter\s+\d+)[A-Za-z]\w*\b',text)
```

If performance is an issue, loading a huge string and parsing it with a Regex wouldn't be the correct method anyway. Just read the file line by line, toss any line that matches `r'^Chapter\s*\d+'` and parse each remaining line separately with `r'\b\w+\b'` :

```
import re

lines=open("huge_file.txt", "r").readlines()

wordlist = []
chapter = re.compile(r'^Chapter\s*\d+')
words = re.compile(r'\b\w+\b')
for line in lines:
  if not chapter.match(line):
    wordlist.extend(words.findall(line))

print len(wordlist)
```

## Performance

I wrote a small ruby script to write a huge file :

```
all_dicts = Dir["/usr/share/dict/*"].map{|dict|
  File.readlines(dict)
}.flatten

File.open('huge_file.txt','w+') do |txt|
  newline=true
  txt.puts "Chapter #{rand(1000)}"
  50_000_000.times do
    if rand<0.05
      txt.puts
      txt.puts
      txt.puts "Chapter #{rand(1000)}"
      newline = true
    end
    txt.write " " unless newline
    newline = false
    txt.write all_dicts.sample.chomp
    if rand<0.10
      txt.puts
      newline = true
    end
  end
end
```

The resulting file has more than 50 million words and is about 483MB big :

```
Chapter 154
schoolyard trashcan's holly's continuations

Chapter 814
assure sect's Trippe's bisexuality inexperience
Dumbledore's cafeteria's rubdown hamlet Xi'an guillotine tract concave afflicts amenity hurriedly whistled
Carranza
loudest cloudburst's

Chapter 142
spender's
vests
Ladoga

Chapter 896
petition's Vijayawada Lila faucets
addendum Monticello swiftness's plunder's outrage Lenny tractor figure astrakhan etiology's
coffeehouse erroneously Max platinum's catbird succumbed nonetheless Nissan Yankees solicitor turmeric's regenerate foulness firefight
spyglass
disembarkation athletics drumsticks Dewey's clematises tightness tepid kaleidoscope Sadducee Cheerios's
```

The two-step process took 12.2s to extract the wordlist on average, the lookahead method took 13.5s and Wiktor's answer also took 13.5s. The lookahead method I first wrote used re.IGNORECASE, and it took around 18s.

There's basically no difference in performance between all the Regexen methods when reading the whole file.

What surprised me though is that the readlines script took around 20.5s, and didn't use much less memory than the other scripts. If you have any idea how to improve the script, please comment!

Comment: this seems to be a simpler solution for the problem at hand

Comment: Thanks. This method is clean, however the trade off here is that the whole text (almost) has to be searched twice.

Comment: True. A few points though: 1. If you don't search gigabytes worth or text, you probably won't notice any difference 2. This code is easier to write, to read, to understand and to debug. This is worth much more than a few ms less during execution. 3. A complex regex with lookarounds, groups or boolean logic can be much slower than 2 separate regexen. You can see the number of steps with https://regex101.com/. My queries require 22+57 steps. The other answer requires 154.

Comment: Eric, you forget that the number of steps at regex101.com does not indicate the real regex performance. **Real regex efficiency should be calculated in the target environment.** Now, what if you need to exclude more phrases? With my approach, all that is necessary is add the alternative without capturing. You will need to eithet use the same grouping in the re.sub that will make the regex performance comparable to my single one or use chained re.subs.

Comment: I updated the answer with 2 alternatives, depending on what's more important to you.

Comment: I don't think it's ok to just split the remaining lines: they could contain a lot of non-words (numbers, punctuations etc.). I think it's better to join the remaing lines as a complete string and then use `\b\w+\b`.

Comment: True. But no need to join the remaining lines, you could end up with a huge string again.

Comment: @EricDuminil well you are right, I think I was being too reluctant to use loops :). Actually with your approach we can compile the regex at the very beginning and then use the already compiled regex in each loop, so that we don't need compilation at each turn.

Answer (score 2):

Match what you do not need and capture what you need, and use this technique with `re.findall` that only returns captured values:

```
re.findall(r'\bChapter\s*\d+\b|\b(\w+)\b',s)
```

Details:

- `\bChapter\s*\d+\b` - `Chapter` as a whole word followed with 0+ whitespaces and 1+ digits
- `|` - or
- `\b(\w+)\b` - match and capture into Group 1 one or more word chars

To avoid getting empty values in the resulting list, filter it (see [demo](http://ideone.com/n7h8af)):

```
import re
s = "Chapter 1: Black brown fox 45"
print(filter(None, re.findall(r'\bChapter\s*\d+\b|\b(\w+)\b',s)))
```

Comment: Thanks. But still the code returns some empty strings `''` along with the words in the list. Also, why are `\b`s needed in the first part?

Comment: This one regex approach seems the cleanest to me. Ido not have time nor a way to test the solution performance although if that is a problem the regex can be written as `r'\b(?:Chapter\s*\d+|(\w+))\b`. Never trust regex101 step count blindly. If you really want to test our solutions set up a test in Python. If you can use PyPi regex module I can suggest a similar regex without having to use `filter`.